# Get value of Name column from SPO list for JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json-formatting, column-formatting, format

[image]

First of all, apologies if this horse has been beaten before but I can't find anything so far to help me out.

I'm trying to do some conditional formatting of a column in a SP list.

One of the columns in the list is Name (it would appear that this is a default column name).  For whatever reason I'm unable to get the following JSON to see a Name column.  I've tried `[$Name]`, which 'seems' like it should work, but even though there is a Name value in each row of the list, the JSON is never picking it up.

Can someone throw me a bone here?

Here's a JSON snippet of what I'm attempting:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$Name]),'pink') != -1, 'STATUS REPORT','')",
  "style": {
    "color": "blue"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$Name]),'pink') != -1, <someurl>, '')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#fieldname),

> You can use this context(`[$FieldName]`) to reference the values of other fields within the same row by specifying the **internal name** of the field surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign: `[$InternalName]`.

So, you need to use the **internal name** of your `Name` column in your JSON code.

Check below URL to find out the internal name of SharePoint column:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint columns](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

**Note**: If you are trying to use `Name` (filename) column in document library then its internal name is `FileLeafRef`. So you can use it like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$FileLeafRef]),'pink') != -1, 'STATUS REPORT','')",
  "style": {
    "color": "blue"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$FileLeafRef]),'pink') != -1, 'https://www.google.com', '')"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I can't find the documentation for this,  it's like looking for water in the desert sometimes when it comes to Sharepoint's little details.  
I appreciate the assistance!