# Get value of Name column from SPO list for JSON formatting in the header

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I'm trying to get the filename of a document name displayed in the header (form header using json formatting).

I tried the below using both $Name and $FileLeafRef but no luck:

```
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "txtContent": "[$Name]"
    }
```

It says it works [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273834/get-value-of-name-column-from-spo-list-for-json-formatting) but maybe its being used in the body or something else.
I need it in the header

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of form JSON formatting. I have also observed this issue while formatting header layout in properties form of SharePoint document library.

Using `[$FileLeafRef]` resulting in blank value even when it is available in page context:

[image]

**Reference**: [Form formatting: In header section [$FileLeafRef], [$FileRef] coming blank](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7964)

---

However, by default when you open document library properties form, it shows document name at the top (SharePoint default functionality):

[image]

Comment: Yes correct Ganesh.
I think i will just use title and use power automate to update the title field

Comment: Yes, for workaround you have to use the Power Automate to update title field. **Note**: Unfortunately you cannot use "Name" column in calculated column formula as well.