# How to get value of Calculated field in Header using JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I have a calculated field based on other multiple columns.

How can I print the value of it in Header?

Comment: Where do you want this exactly, on New item form, display form edit form? Do you see the calculated column in SharePoint default display/edit forms?

Comment: I think there are some issues with calculated column as well while using in JSON. Similar to this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306211/get-value-of-name-column-from-spo-list-for-json-formatting-in-the-header/306215#306215

Comment: Hi @Thangho, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this from my end and I am able to reproduce this issue. I think this is a bug while using calculated column in JSON form formatting.

The calculated column value is available in the page context but it is not shown in form header:

[image]

I have raised a new bug/issue here: [JSON Form formatting: Unable to use the calculated column value in header/footer layout customization](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8788). Hopefully Microsoft will fix this in near future.

**Similar thread**: [Get value of Name column from SPO list for JSON formatting in the header](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306211/get-value-of-name-column-from-spo-list-for-json-formatting-in-the-header/306215#306215)